# How to have access to a class created with template literals?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
displayOneCam(getDetail){
  // let lenses = await this.numberOfLenses();
  let html = "";
  let cardHtml =
    `
      <div class="card">
        <img src="${getDetail.imageUrl}" alt="camera1">
          <h2>${getDetail.name}</h2>
          <p>${getDetail.price/100}$</p>
          <p>${getDetail.description}</p>
          <label for="lenses">Lenses</label>
          <input list="lenses">
            <datalist id="lenses">

            </datalist>
          </input>
          <a href="cart.html" class="linkCart btn btn-primary">Add To Cart</a>
      </div>`;


  html+= cardHtml;
  const products = document.querySelector(this.productClass);
  products.innerHTML = html;

}
```

in another method I d like to get the element class "card"

I did this but it doesn't work, it returns null when i try to log the result in the console
Thank you for your help :)

```
setStorage(){
       var info = document.querySelector(".card");
       console.log(info);
}
```

Comment: In what order are the functions being executed?

Comment: DisplayOneCam is executed 1st

Comment: Then it should work. Once the element is added to the DOM, it doesn't matter how it was added. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is the `await` line commented out in the real code, like it is here? If the real function is asynchronous, you need to wait until it completes before calling `setStorage`.

Comment: Yes I commented it out, I forgot to get rid of the await keyword  ;) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in another method

Not sure what your class structure is. But the below works. As long as `displayOneCam()` method is called before you try access the element, it will work.

```js
class Class_55030705 {
  constructor(pClass) {
    this.productClass = pClass;
  }
  displayOneCam(getDetail) {
    // let lenses = await this.numberOfLenses();
    let html = "";
    let cardHtml =
      `
      <div class="card">
        <img src="${getDetail.imageUrl}" alt="camera1">
          <h2>${getDetail.name}</h2>
          <p>${getDetail.price/100}$</p>
          <p>${getDetail.description}</p>
          <label for="lenses">Lenses</label>
          <input list="lenses">
            <datalist id="lenses">

            </datalist>
          </input>
          <a href="cart.html" class="linkCart btn btn-primary">Add To Cart</a>
      </div>`;


    html += cardHtml;
    const products = document.querySelector(this.productClass);
    products.innerHTML = html;

    return this; //This has only been added to allow chaining.
  }

  setStorage() {
    document.querySelector(".card").style.border = '1px solid red';
  }
}

const class_55030705 = new Class_55030705('.target-container');

class_55030705.displayOneCam({
  imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=100',
  name: 'Name',
  price: 50,
  description: "Description here."
}).setStorage();
```

```html
<div class="target-container"></div>
```